# Creating a reusable UIView subclass - running into sizing issues

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying to create a small reusable view for the "tags" at the bottom ("PC-12 Restricted" and "PC-24 Restricted").

[image]

This is the code I have, and mostly it's working.

```swift
class TagView: UIView {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
  }

  private let label = UILabel()

  func setup() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "Placeholder"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)
    addSubview(label)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
      label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
      label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 4),
      label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
    ])
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
  }

  func configure(tag: Tag) {
    label.text = tag.label
    backgroundColor = tag.backgroundColor
  }
}
```

However, when I place it inside a UIStackView inside of a UITableViewCell, it moves outside of the stackview? Also, I added two of these TagViews, but they are showing on top of each other!

[image]

When I use the view debugger in Xcode, I get some exclamation marks with the following info:

[image]

[image]

Why is the position ambiguous? What am I missing? When I print the TagViews that I am adding to my view hierarchy, I do see that they have a frame with everything set to 0, but when I look in the view debugger, they do have a frame.

```swift
let tagViews = airport.tags.map { tag -> TagView in
  let tagView = TagView()
  tagView.configure(tag: tag)
  return tagView
}

print(tagViews)

for view in tagViews {
  tagsStackView.addSubview(view)
}
```

```
[<MyApp.TagView: 0x7f81ac449570; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600001afaba0>>, <MyApp.TagView: 0x7f81ac449c70; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x600001afae60>>]
```

---

Edit:

If I add two TagViews to my the UIStackView inside of my UITableViewCell .xib file, it works fine:

[image]

But when I instantiate and add them programmatically, I have the layout problems as described.

---

Edit 2:

I have a very small test project so you can reproduce the problem: https://github.com/kevinrenskers/TagViewTest

Comment: Have you set the UIStackView properties. there are properties like Alignment, Distribution, Spacing. plase chage that accordingly and check

Comment: Nothing special there. Just a horizontal stack with distribution and alignment both set to fill, and spacing set to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. And I feel stupid ‍♂️

```
tagsStackView.addSubview(tagView)
```

should of course be

```
tagsStackView.addArrangedSubview(tagView)
```